# How to get the value of a bit at a certain positions from a byte array?

Tags: c#, byte, bit

```
byte[] sample = new byte[]{10,20,30};
```

-the value is 6 bits and started from third bit (from right to left)

new byte[]{10,20,30} looks like "00001010 00010100 00011110" (should be in order like bytes order)
so i need "00001010 00010100 ***000111***10" 
-my value is 7

the solution based on help(answer 1 by **Yaur**), just bits direction changed

```
   public static bool GetValue(byte[] data, int position)
        {
            var bytePos = data.Length - 1 - position / 8;//right -> left
            //var bytePos = position / 8;//left -> right
            var bitPos = position % 8;

            return ((data[bytePos] & (1 << bitPos)) != 0);//right -> left
            //return ((data[bytePos] & (1 << (7 - bitPos))) != 0); //left -> right
        }

        public static long GetValue(byte[] data, int position, int length)
        {
            if (length > 62)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("not going to work properly with 63 bits if the first bit is 1");
            }
            long retv = 0;
            for (int i = position + length - 1; i > position - 1; i--)
            //for(int i = position;i<position+length;i++)//left -> right
            {
                if (GetValue(data, i)) retv |= 1;
                retv = retv << 1;
            }
            retv = retv >> 1;
            return retv;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. Can you explain more what you mean in this part "new byte[]{10,20,30} is "1010 10100 11110" and i need ..."?

Comment: BitArray does not have a `.Copy(byte[])` function. Is that supposed to be `CopyTo` or is that a extension method?

Comment: Divide by 8 to find the byte index. The remainder is the bit index within that byte.

Comment: `new byte[]{10,20,30}` is not `1010 10100 11110`. It's `00011110 00010100 00001010`.

Comment: yes, my mistake, it is 00001010 00010100 00011110 (should be in order like bytes order - every byte i have to see separately and successively)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for most inputs:

```
public bool GetValue(byte[] data, int position) 
{
    var bytePos = position / 8;
    var bitPos = position % 8;
    return ((data[bytePos] & (1 << bitPos))!=0)
    // depending on the order in which you expect the bits you might need this instead
    //return ((data[bytePos] & (1 << (7-bitPos)))!=0)

}

public long GetValue(byte[] data, int position, int length) 
{
    if(length > 62)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("not going to work properly with 63 bits if the first bit is 1");
    }
    long retv=0;
    for(int i = position;i<position+length;i++)
    {
         if(GetValue(data,i)
         {
             retv |=1;
         }
         retv = retv << 1;
    }
    retv = retv >> 1;
}
```

Comment: did you mean "retv = retv << 1" and "return retv = retv >> 1;"?...  i try this but looks like something wrong - maybe the problem is in reversing bits before make complete the value?

Comment: that is correct, I fixed it in the answer and added code to get the bits from high order to low order.

Comment: still cannot get the value 7 :) in any case something wrong :( really i am not sure that i am understand what your code doing :(

Comment: 7 is the correct answer if you are dealing with this as a bit stream.  what would you expect if you passed a position of 13 and a length of 8 `100 000111` or `11100`?

Comment: byte[] {10,20,30} is "00001010 00010100 00011110" - bytes should be converted to bits in "as it order", than if i need value from position 13 and length of 8, i should get this value from right side like in windows calculator: 0000 /*1010 0001*/ 0100 00011110, so my value is 1010 0001